# Should DIR-615 router protect control pages with a passord?

Tags: networking, router, security, control-panel

I have a DIR-615 router on address `192.168.10.1`

If I open an URL `http://192.168.10.1` then I get login page

But if I enter `http://192.168.10.1/Basic/Wireless.shtml` I get into control panel without any password asking.

Is this by design?

I mean, if entering router control panel is not password protected from internal network?

**UPDATE**

I was entering different URL's from different browsers, including `curl` and `wget` command line utilities, but from one computer.

Answer (score 0):

It is password protected, but requesting `http://192.168.10.1/Basic/Wireless.shtml` works because you are still logged in. As long as you are, the router does not distinguish between you accessing the page through a link on the control panel and you accessing the page by entering the URL directly after browsing some unrelated websites.

You are not automatically logged out by leaving the configuration pages, although it may seem that way because the URL `http://192.168.10.1` presents the login screen, regardless of whether you are logged in already. Eventually, your session will expire and you will no longer be able to circumvent the password prompt by accessing one of the configuration pages directly. Although the DIR-615 does not have a 'log out' button, you can force a logout by entering an incorrect password in the login screen. Afterwards, you can convince yourself the trick no longer works and shows 'Not Found' instead.

Comment: How does router identifies me as "me"? By `IP` address?

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Yes.